# 3D Phase portrait of Rössler System using Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm running into a specific problem when attempting to plot the 3D phase portrait of the Rössler system in Python. The problem is that certain arrows are excessively long, and thus the visualization isn't a good one at all:
[Bad 3d phase portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD8Eg.jpg)
This is my code so far, and I don't really know what to alter to make an appropriate plot. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
# Axes, grid

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = plt.axes(projection ='3d')

x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-20, 20, 4),
                      np.arange(-20, 20, 4),
                      np.arange(0, 20, 4))

# Define vector field

u = -y - z
v = x + (1/5)*y
w = 1/5 + (x - 5/2)*z

# Plot vector field

ax.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w, length=0.1, normalize = False)

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

plt.show()
```

I haven't been able to try any alternatives largely because I'm not really sure of what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you won't be able to accurately visualize this vector field with quivers, because there is quite a big variation in magnitude in your view area. A better way is to visualize streamlines, and that's not easy either:

1. matplotlib doesn't support 3D streamlines.
2. Plotly support streamtubes, but when I tried it on my vector fields I usually got "mehhh" results, meaning it was really difficult to get them to proper scale.
3. I believe that the easiest solution is to use the [SymPy Plotting Backend module](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html), which exposes a `plot_vector` function that also plot streamlines. Note that I am the developer of this module, so I'm going to showcase it for you. In particular, this module exposes a backend to create plots with [K3D-Jupyter](https://github.com/K3D-tools/K3D-jupyter/) which, for this particular vector field, produces excellent results.

```py
from sympy import *
from spb import *
var("x:z, u:w")

u = -y - z
v = x + (1/5)*y
w = 1/5 + (x - 5/2)*z

plot_vector(
    [u, v, w], (x, -20, 20), (y, -20, 20), (z, 0, 20), # vector field and ranges
    backend=KB,         # chose the plotting library: K3D-Jupyter
    streamlines=True,   # enable or disable streamlines
    stream_kw={         # customize streamlines
        "starts": True, # Ask the streamlines to start from random points
        "npoints": 150  # number of starting points for the streamlines
    },
    n=50, # number of discretization points. Don't go too crazy as memory requirements is at least n^3
    use_cm=True, # use color map. Colors indicates the magnitude of the vector field.
)
```

[image]

In order to use the streamline functionalities, you will have to install all the requirements, which are quite heavy (If I recall correctly, at least 200MB).

```
pip install sympy_plot_backends[all]
```